# discord.js guildCreate and guildDelete not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, event-handling

I am using discord.js to create a bot and have been following their guide until now to create the command and event handlers, including their format of putting each event handler and command function in its own file with its own exported module. This has worked fine for the 'ready' and 'interactionCreate' events, but for some reason my 'guildCreate' and 'guildDelete' events do not seem to be doing anything.

Here is how I am setting up the event listeners:

```
const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventFiles = fs
    .readdirSync(eventsPath)
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));

eventFiles.forEach((file) => {
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
});
```

Here is the contents of guildCreate.js (guildDelete.js is the same except the name of the event is 'guildDelete'):

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'guildCreate',
    execute(guild) {
        console.log('joined guild');
        console.log(guild.name);
    },
};
```

I'm not sure why this is not printing anything as I can't see how it differs from the way the ready event is handled in the guide and that is working fine for me (https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/event-handling.html#individual-event-files).

Comment: I'm not updated on the Discord API, but I heard you need to explicitly provide intents now? Is there an intent for guild events and did you specify it?

Comment: @catgirlkelly I have given it administrator intents so I believe that should provide it with access to those?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that setting the intents to be 8 (the administrator permissions as calculated using the bit math calculator in the Discord Developer Portal) does not include access to guild events and I had to specifically set Intents.Flags.GUILDS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When initialising Discord.js with ClientOptions, you need to specify the "Guilds" intent in order to be able to access join & leave events.

```
const discordConfig: ClientOptions = {
    intents: ['Guilds']
};

const client = new Client(discordConfig);
```

[Discord.js Docs](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#error-disallowed-intents)

[Discord Docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents)